# Multilingual Application support in Windows CE?

Tags: .net, localization, windows-ce, multilingual

What are some of the considerations needed when adding multilingual support for a .NET application designed to run in Windows CE (5)?

Answer (score 1):

The use of resource files is probably the way to go.  I'm actually working on a .NET mobile app as well and found this tutorial series very helpful:

http://www.dotnetfordevices.com/articles/50.html

It not only covers some basics of localization, but also an idea of how to target both the Standard and Professional platforms of Windows Mobile 6 (which I think could also work for version 5).  The only real difference between Standard and Professional as far as I know is touchscreen, so I think you could really benefit from consolidation of your code base as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only the app that needs localization, then the considerations are the same as with any app.  All string should come from a resource file.  Be aware that there is no such thing as Thread.CurrentCulture, so you have to track the locale for the app manually.